# How do you customize Omniscript Save for Later message?

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript

I'm trying to figure out a way to customise the message 'Your OmniScript is saved for later' displayed to user when an Omniscript flow is saved by the user. This message is too technical for users.

[image]

There isn't any helpful setting I can see to do this (below).

[image]

I tried to find anything useful in the setup-> JSON editor. But it doesn't seem to apply to the page message (below).
[image]

Any help/ideas how we can change this message to a more user friendly one?

Thanks!